# Password invalid for sqlplus copy command but it is the correct password. Please guide me on it

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, ora-01017

I am using this command .

```
COPY FROM username/[pwd]@identifier 
  INSERT SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME USING SELECT * FROM SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME;
```

and my password contains `+, )` .

it is showing me this error ORA-01017.

The password and the username and all are other details are true.

Please help me on this and any guidance on it is deeply appreciated.

Comment: does it works with the simple `sqlplus username/"[pwd]"@identifier` ? otherwise you might not have the right password indeed.

Comment: I am unable to login. Getting this error                                                                     ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor. But its the correct password.

Comment: `)` or `$` might also be an issue in the password. Either try to escape them with `\`. Now your talking about a different error: ask your admin to restart the listener and check your identifier with her...

Answer (score 0):

If your password has the special characters then in **cmd.exe**, it should be something like this:

```
username/\"password\"@tns_alias
```

here `\"` is used for denoting the double-quotes. so your password is wrapped in double-quotes.

Comment: Nope not working sir. Please suggest any alternatives. I am facing ORA-01017 error the passwords are correct.

Comment: Are you able to login in command prompt using `sqlplus username/\"password\"@tns_alias`

Comment: I am using it with the copy command i am using it in this format      username/"password"@tns_alias . It is fine for me . but for the above mentioned password with those special characters its failing.

Comment: Request you to please answer my question in comment.

Comment: Its not working. but if i use sqlplus sqlplus username/"password"@tns_alias its working sir.